# Замена значений в определенном столбце DataFrame по словарю

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

Нужно заменить значения в определенном столбце DataFrame по словарю, при этом, если ключ словаря не найден, нужно удалить всю строку из DataFrame.

Я смог выполнить задачу так:

```
dict1 = {'Car': 'c', 'Motorcycle': 'mt', 'Truck': 'tr'}
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product': 'Truck Motorcycle Car Car Tire Wheel Truck'.split(),
                   'Price': [10000, 5000, 23000, 15000, 500, 300, 8000]})
df['Product_new'] = df['Product'].map(dict1)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df.drop('Product', axis=1, inplace=True)
df_new = df.reindex(columns=['Product_new', 'Price'])
```

Возможно ли заменить значения сразу в столбце `Product`, не создавая промежуточный столбец и избавиться от строк, по которым не найден ключ в словаре?

Пытался через `replace`, но как-то не получилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А в чём собственно проблема? Всё работает и если сразу в `Product` писать:

```
import pandas as pd
dict1 = {'Car': 'c', 'Motorcycle': 'mt', 'Truck': 'tr'}
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product': 'Truck Motorcycle Car Car Tire Wheel Truck'.split(),
                   'Price': [10000, 5000, 23000, 15000, 500, 300, 8000]})
df['Product'] = df['Product'].map(dict1)
df.dropna(inplace=True)

    Product Price
0   tr  10000
1   mt  5000
2   c   23000
3   c   15000
6   tr  8000
```

Answer (score 4):

Вот еще один вариант (однострочник):

```
df = (df
      .query("Product in @dict1.keys()")
      .assign(Product=lambda x: x["Product"].replace(dict1)))
```

---

результат:

```
In [84]: df
Out[84]:
  Product  Price
0      tr  10000
1      mt   5000
2       c  23000
3       c  15000
6      tr   8000
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
df["Product"] = df["Product"].map(dict1).fillna(np.nan)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

результат:

```
  Product  Price
0      tr  10000
1      mt   5000
2       c  23000
3       c  15000
6      tr   8000
```